# How to add javascript variables into a URL

Tags: javascript

I have this link :

```
https://apiyouflow.com/
```

and I have these variables :

```
v1=4;
v2=3;
```

I want to add them in URL to be like this:

```
https://apiyouflow.com/4/4
```

How to add javascript variables into a URL

Comment: You build a string and update it?

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation **[using the `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String)**:

```js
var url = "https://apiyouflow.com/";
v1=4;
v2=3;

var concatenated = url + v1 + "/" + v2;
console.log(concatenated);
```

String concatenation using the **[`string.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat)** method:

```js
var url = "https://apiyouflow.com/";
v1=4;
v2=3;

var concatenated = url.concat(v1, "/", v2);
console.log(concatenated);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [`location.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign)

```
location.assign(`/${v1}/${v2}`);
```